# GeoServer limits number of SQL View parameters?

Tags: geoserver

I tried to create a sql view with 53 params, but when I clicked at "Guess parameters from SQL" it showed only 25 params.

If you have had this issue, is there a workaround?

The featuretype.xml file contains all 53 parameters, the problem seems to be on the sql view interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very likely a limitation of the UI, the component used is pageable and would show at most 25 elements... I guess the code was setup so that it's not paging, but the limit is still there?

Should be an easy fix, please open a ticket at https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary